# QGIS starts a query "ST_SummaryStatsAgg()" on PostGIS3.0 for a raster and needs more than 10min to load

Tags: qgis, raster, postgis, statistics

I am working on a test-server (RAID6) implementing PostgreSQL/PostGIS with vector and raster support. The aim is a big database sharing different data types including high resolution (0.5m, also 0.1m; 8 bit; 3 bands) rasters and (2m, also 0.5m; 32bit floating point; 1 band) rasters.

Adding vector data in QGIS is no problem and relatively fast. Also, 8 bit rasters with 3 bands are relatively fast, below 1min.

But when I try to add a PostGIS raster with 32 bit floating point and a resolution of 2m into QGIS the query `SELECT ST_SummaryStatsAgg()` needs a lot of time at least 10-20 minutes on database.

Is there any way to store the raster band statistics of the mentioned query within the PostGIS raster to avoid the mentioned loading time?

Maybe with something like:

```
ALTER TABLE dem_table SELECT (ST_SummaryStats(dem_table.rast)).* INTO dem_table FROM dem_table;
```

Or with using a constraint? Or changing options in QGIS?

Comment: How big (number of pixels) is that image?

Comment: @RafDouglas: The number of pixels for the 2m resolution raster are 10'773'483'520 including nodata pixels. (calculated with SELECT ST_CountAgg(rast, 1, false)).

Comment: 10.7Gpixels @32 bit is about 43GBytes of (raw/uncompressed) data. Is the query running on an adequate machine/server? Loading a file like that could easily hit the RAM limit of your PostgreSQL server (and start swapping) and/or incur into bandwidth bottlenecks (if on a remote machine). How much physical RAM is there on the server nad how much allocated to PostgreSQL?

Comment: @RafDouglas: The server has 96 GB of physical RAM. PostgreSQL configuartion properties are: shared_buffers=23GB, effective_cache_size=71GB. If you need further Infos I you can find in the postgresql.conf file. [link] (https://file.io/tUBxCVRwg4PW)

Comment: Would you mind trying an `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on the query?  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-explain.html

Comment: @RafDouglas: "The result of: EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT (ST_SummaryStatsAgg( "rast", 1, TRUE, 0 )).* FROM dem_table;"

Aggregate  (cost=12545.81..12545.82 rows=1 width=48) (actual time=682847.794..682847.795 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on dem_table  (cost=0.00..10079.92 rows=164392 width=168) (actual time=2.297..221.814 rows=164392 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.060 ms
Execution Time: 682847.830 ms

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134689/discussion-between-gisp-and-rafdouglas).

Comment: A further interesting aspect i discovered is, that the long lasting Query St_summarystatsAgg() only appears on a windows client with QGIS. When a ubuntu client is used the loading time is fast.

Comment: See bug reference in github:
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/47815

Answer (score 0):

The [bug](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/47815) has now been fixed and `ST_SummaryStatsAgg` should use fast overviews instead with QGIS 3.34.1 and QGIS 3.28.13.